# Como remover um arquivo da staging area no git?

Tags: git

Acidentalmente adicionei todos os arquivos na staging area do git com o comando "git add .", como fazer para remover um arquivo da staging area para ele não ser commitado?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Como aparece mencionado na mensagem do `git status` (*use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage*), o comando é:

`git reset HEAD <file>...`

Se você quiser remover um arquivo:

```
git reset HEAD caminho/para/o/arquivo
```

Se você quiser limpar todo o *staging*, vá para o diretório raiz do repositório e use o comando:

```
git reset HEAD *
```

Comment: Uma maneira de evitar acidentes como esse no futuro é adicionar os arquivos incrementalmente com o comando `git add -p` (*patch mode*). Isso permite com que você adicione cada alteração individualmente. (Sugestão do usuário @molusco: muito obrigado! Preferi adicionar como comentário ao invés de incluir na resposta.)

Comment: Sobre como evitar acidentes, acho que `git add -u` está mais próximo do resultado pretendido. Não acrescenta arquivos novos e não pede confirmação de cada trecho modificado.

Answer (score 1):

A partir da versão 2.23.0 do Git ([de Agosto de 2019](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.23.0.txt)), foi criado o [comando `git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) ([juntamente com o `git switch`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/533866/112052)), que passa a ser uma alternativa ao `git reset` mencionado na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5150/112052) (mas claro que `reset` ainda funciona).

Enfim, nas versões mais novas, a mensagem do `git status` (quando há arquivos no *staging area* que ainda não foram *commitados*) é:

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
... lista dos arquivos
```

Ou seja, agora a própria mensagem do Git dá preferência ao novo comando. Portanto, para remover arquivos do *staging area* basta fazer:

```bash
git restore --staged nome-arquivo

# ou, para vários arquivos
git restore --staged nome-arquivo1 nome-arquivo2 nome-arquivo3

# ou, para todos os arquivos que estiverem no staging area
git restore --staged .
```

---

Vale lembrar que **para este caso específico** os comandos `reset` e `restore` são equivalentes. Mas há diferenças entre eles, dependendo do que for feito (porém já foge do escopo da pergunta, mas em todo caso, [veja aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58003030) para mais detalhes).