# Como desfazer um "git add" antes de um commit?

Tags: git

Eu adicionei por engano `arquivos` usando o comando `git add` e ainda não executei um `git commit`. Existe uma maneira de desfazer ou remover esses arquivos do commit?

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como remover um arquivo da staging area no git?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5149/como-remover-um-arquivo-da-staging-area-no-git)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Para desfazer a inclusão de um item faça:

```
git reset <nomearquivo>
```

Se você fez `git add .`, pode desfazer a inclusão de todos os arquivos de uma vez, fazendo:

```
git reset
```